# Why does io:format support ~n when \n does the same thing?

Tags: erlang, escaping, erlang-otp

These two give identical output:

```
1> io:format("Hello, world!~n").
Hello, world!
ok
2> io:format("Hello, world!\n").
Hello, world!
ok
```

Why does `io:format` support `~n` when `\n` does the same thing? Are there any differences?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to "Programming Erlang", `~n` outputs the platform-specific new line sequence (`\n` on Unix, `\r\n` on Windows, etc.). I think `\n` just writes the `\n` character, but am not sure.

Comment: Yes, the `\n` is just a normal character so it is output as is. Otherwise, yes, you are right, the `~n` is intended for a platform specific new line.

Comment: True, but it could have been.

Comment: I wonder if it would still be possible to patch, or if too many programs will break under Windows if ~n suddenly generates CRLF, because it's never been like that before.

Answer (score 0):

According to [io document](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html), `The general format of a control sequence is ~F.P.PadModC`. So the format must begin with `~`, and character `n` is one of the control sequences with the definition `Writes a new line`. `\n` is not a format.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood this question.