# File IO and list processing

Tags: erlang

I asked a similar question, not sure what wasnt clear about it but I'll try again. I have a file. File name is file.txt, I read file.txt in to a list. Now I can print this to the console and it will show:

```
blah
blah
blah
blah
```

That is fine. Perfect :) Now how would I forward that to a new file? so that the new file contains:

```
blah
blah
blah
blah
```

Nothing more and nothing less. Here is the code I am using to read a file in to a list:
    {ok, Device} = file:open("file.txt", [read]),
    Li = readdata(Device, []).

```
readdata(Device, Accum) ->
case io:get_line(Device, "") of
    eof  -> file:close(Device), Accum;
    Line -> readdata(Device, Accum ++ [Line])
end.
```

So again, the new file with display EXACTLY what the file I read displays, no extra characters, not all on 1 line..etc.. just the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easy way is:

```
ok = file:write_file("output.txt", Li).
```

As you may see in http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html , there are plenty of useful functions like file:read_file/1 that may shorten your program and at the same time make it a little quicker.

You see, the way you combine read data with accumulator is not perfect because it requires copying of Accum values, so the complexity of your readdata/2 function is N^2. Appending to the head of the list is the best way but of course you'd have to store lines as values of Acc and reverse it in the end.

And what about the length of the file? If it is huge and doesn't fit into memory, you'll have problems using even working with accumulator properly. The standard way in this case is to open both files, read some chunk of data and immediately write it to the output.

```
copy_file() ->
    {ok, In} = file:open("input", [read]),
    {ok, Out} = file:open("output", [write]),
    copy_file(In, Out),
    file:close(In),
    file:close(Out).

copy_file(In, Out) ->
    case file:read(In, 1024 * 64) of
        {ok, Data} ->
            ok = file:write(Out, Data),
            copy_file(In, Out);
        _ ->
            ok
    end.
```

I haven't tried the code, it may not compile, I just tried to show the basic idea.

Comment: the files are pretty small, in other languages its as simply as:

`data[] = file.read("file.txt")`
`open = file.open("new.txt")`
`foreach (line in data)`
`file.write(open, line)`
`end`
`

I actually dont want to "copy" a file, that was just the definition i was using to explain that i want to write the list of data to a new file exactly as how it appeared in the other file. I may wish to modify the list and write it back to the same file.. so copying was just a term i used.

Comment: Erlang's lists module does have a foreach function that is intended for processing side-effects on a list. You could look at that.  I'll try put an answer together with some code examples.

Comment: i have used foreach, for some reason the output appears to be all on 1 line in the file, i've tried foreach and map with the same result.

Comment: i think i have found the problem, for some reason ~n is not working, i am on windows a newline is \r\n but for some reason i think erlang is giving me a unix \n .. how can i change this?

Comment: There is a sentence in the documentation for file:read_line/1:
"The line is returned including the LF, but excluding any CR immediately followed by a LF." You either have to use another function to read lines from the file, or you need to chop off the last character and append windows' line ending symbols.

Comment: @ace007 -  I would have expected the ~n format to be platform agnostic. I don't have erlang running on a windows platform.  You might want to look at io:nl/1 (http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#nl-0)

Comment: There is some discussion about this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215033/why-does-ioformat-support-n-when-n-does-the-same-thing . It seams that is was "intended" to be platform specific, but was never implemented as such.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with. I modified your readdata/2 slightly to optimize the append and remove the newline.  The write/2 function uses lists:foreach/2 and io:fwrite/3 to write to the file.

```
-module(rwlist).
-export([read/1,write/2]).

read(FileName) ->
   case file:open(FileName, [read]) of
      {ok, Device} ->
         readdata(Device, [])
   end.

readdata(Device, Accum) ->
   case io:get_line(Device, "") of
       eof  -> file:close(Device), lists:reverse(Accum);
       Line -> readdata(Device, [(Line--"\n")|Accum])
   end.

write(FileName, List) ->
   case file:open(FileName, [write]) of
      {ok, Device} ->
         lists:foreach(fun(Line) -> writeline(Device, Line) end, List),
         file:close(Device)
   end.

writeline(Device, Line) -> writeline(Device, Line, os:type()).

writeline(Device, Line, {win32,_}) -> io:fwrite(Device, "~s\r\n", [Line]);
writeline(Device, Line, _) -> io:fwrite(Device, "~s\n", [Line]).
```

Here's the test...

```
57> List=rwlist:read("list").  
["item 1","item 2","item 3","item 4"]
58> rwlist:write("list2", List).
ok
59> List2=rwlist:read("list2"). 
["item 1","item 2","item 3","item 4"]
```

Of course if you are just copying a file Dmitry's answer is better.

Comment: I modified the sample code to add an OS specific writeline/2 function since the Erlang formatter doesn't do it for us.